# pyPubmed API_Key not found?

Tags: api-key, pubmed, pubmed-api

I get this error. How to fix this?

`$ pubmed advance-search [2023-05-29 11:08:50 Eutils validate_api_key WARNING MainThread:234]  API_KEY not found! Use eutils with a api_key is a good idea!`

I tried the command
`$ export NCBI_API_KEY=xxxx`

But I keep getting this message.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by repeating the execution of the command `export NCBI_API_KEY=xxxx`. Eventually, it accepted :)